# aprirtc call_crossing_detected error when calling from android to android

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, webrtc

My ionic angularjs corodova app works great when receiving calls from the demo web page on chrome.  When I try to initiate a call to the demo site or another device, whether using demo API key or real api key, i get
call_crossing_detected

What does this mean, and how do you fix it?

More details on symptoms.  When this occurs, no video comes up and the initiating device shows the error and the call button remains.  But the receiving device switches to the hangup button, which then works.  And if you speak into either device the receiving device receives the audio, but nothing on the initiating device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. It was caused by apiRTC.init executing more than once.

Answer (score 0):

"call_crossing_detected" reason appears on hangup event when a call is already established between the two users and you are trying to establish a new one.
So I think you may have an issue on the first call hangup.

Comment: This is the First call, so no clue what is going.  I switched to the debugging library so we could get more info.https://cloud.apizee.com/apiRTC/apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js

Comment: link to console logging https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0902q4xvldc1vf/console.log?dl=0

Comment: as a test I removed media-with-compression and put in regular cordova media addon, and no change.  I am using media_with_compression to allow m4a to be recorded and played on both ios and android, otherwise android will not support it.

Comment: I have resolved this issue.  It was caused by apiRTC.init executing more than once.